# Setting httpPort for Jetty Grails plugin

Tags: grails, jetty

I want to change the httpPort from the default of 8080 for the Jetty Grails plugin. I cannot set the Jetty httpPort property via a system property and/or Gradle property.

```
System property: gradle jettyRun -DjettyHttpPort=9090
Gradle property (gradle.properties): jettyHttpPort=9090
```

Right now you have to make a change to your Gradle build script (like adding a configuration task) to make this work. There are JettyPluginConventions with a function to setHttpPort(int) but I do not know how to implement it.

http://www.gradle.org/releases/1.0-milestone-3/docs/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/jetty/JettyPluginConvention.html#setHttpPort(java.lang.Integer)

http://www.gradle.org/jetty_plugin.html

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, and documentation for Gradle is very general and vague. I sometimes think that only Gradle developers are able to get full potential of this great tool :)

Right now the way is to add following to gradle build script:

```
jettyRun {
    httpPort = 9000
}
```

It looks you cannot set this value in command line. There was an issue for that, [GRADLE-1224](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1224), but it was closed as "Won't Fix" because

> The [Jetty plugin has been deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes#jetty-plugin) and is scheduled to be removed with Gradle 4.0. We are not going to work on this issue anymore.

Comment: Shorter version: `jettyRun.httpPort = 9000`

Comment: Or even `[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.with { httpPort = 8887 }`

Answer (score 1):

You can set properties like httpPort via [JettyPluginConvention](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyPluginConvention.html)

```
convention.plugins.jetty.httpPort = 9090
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with below command

```
gradle jettyRun -DhttpPort=9000
```

However, the task **jettyRunWar** doesn't seem to pick port 9000 and still uses default port. May be a bug in gradle jetty plug-in.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried -Djetty.port=9090 as a **JVM parameter**?